# Lua check if a string is a decimal integer

Tags: lua

How do I determine whether a string is an integer in lua? For example `isInteger("123")`, should be true. And `isIntger("abc")` and `isIntger("12.3")` should be false.

Answer (score 8):

Starting with Lua 5.2 you can use [`tonumber`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-tonumber) to accomplish that. If you put second argument in it, the string will be treated as a number that should be an integer in `base`:

```lua
print(tonumber("145.5", 10)) -- nil
print(tonumber("145", 10)) -- 145
print(tonumber("-145", 10)) -- -145
```

In Lua 5.1 the situation is different as `tonumber` even with specified `base` accepts any number not only integers. I would probably use [`string.match`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.match):

```lua
print(("145.5"):match("^%-?%d+$")) -- nil
print(("145"):match("^%-?%d+$")) -- "145"
print(("-145"):match("^%-?%d+$")) -- "-145"
```

Patterns are described in section [5.4.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1).

Having these values you can easily use them as booleans whenever needed, and also as actual integers when you need them. If you are looking for simpler strict boolean-only result, see Piglet's answer; it describes such intent better. I rarely run into such need, hence I suggest to use `nil`/value alternatives. It's a commonly used approach in Lua.

Comment: How about integers < 0 in Lua 5.1?

Comment: @LeszekMazur Here you go, it was missing; good notice.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply search for anything that is not a digit.

```
local function isInteger(str)

  return not (str == "" or str:find("%D"))  -- str:match("%D") also works

end
```